# Loop through checkbox and display the value of checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm looping through multiple checkboxes and inside the loop I need to be able to display value of checboxes are checked.How to do that?

So far, this is my code:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
   var answer = $("#SelectedAnswer").val();
   $("input:checked").each(function () {
      alert("Checkbox: " + answer);
   });
});
```

My checkbox is looping in table that hold the value

```
<table class="table" id="polo">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan=""></th>
        <%
        for(int a = 1; a < 4; a++){         
        %>
        <th>PO <%=a %></th>
        <%
        }
        %>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <%
        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){         
    %>
    <tr>
        <td id="loid">LO <%=i %></td>
        <%
        for(int x = 1; x < 4; x++){         
        %>
        <td id="sempo"><input type="checkbox" name="poid" id="poid" value="po <%=x %>" class="checkbox-primary"></td>
        <%
        }
        %>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</tbody>
```

Sorry for the newb question. I'm kinda new to jquery.

Comment: Where do you need to display the values?

Comment: @MHRasel  I just want to display in alert only for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need to fix your selector

try this

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
     $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        alert("Checkbox: " + $(this).val());
     });
  });
```